# Receiving an error when trying to call newGame function

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to set up an event listener that is 'listening' as soon as the game is initialized. But when I load the page I get the following error:

```
hangman.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: newGame is not a function
    at init (hangman.js:10)
    at hangman.js:191
```

Here is the related code:

```
var init = function (){
  var timer;
  input = prompt('Please enter a guessable word:  ')
  welcome.textContent = 'Player 1 has entered a word. Player two may begin guessing';
  word.textContent = input;
  setTimeout(invisibleOpener, 13000);
  newGame()

}


var newGame = function(){
  startGame.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log('test');
  })
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `init()`? I bet you do it between the two blocks of code that you showed... So you call `init` which then calls `newGame` _before_ you define `newGame`, hence the error. Either call it _afterwards_ or replace `var newGame = function ()` by `function newGame ()` so that its gets hoisted.

Comment: Read about Javascript hoisting you will get answer https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript